# Json String of Data in Month and Day

Tags: android

I have a string like this: "2014-01-23T11: 11:05 +0100" from my JSON

I want to retrieve only the day and month

example:

March 1

any ideas?

Comment: yeap, you need to use some classes ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] d = date.split("T");
String[] correct_date = d[0].split("-");
```

Then retrieve the values (day & month) needed from correct_date.